# Error suppressor not suppressing as indicated in the manual for a non-defined function

Tags: php

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> Warning Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even
>   disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
>   execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to
>   suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available
>   or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no
>   indication as to why.

However this code when run:

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
@foo();
echo 'earth';
```

Displays and logs (for me):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function foo() in /var/www/stackoverflow/error-suppressor.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/stackoverflow/error-suppressor.php on line 3
```

Which appears counter to the manual.  What am I missing here?

Php version used here: 7.1.12.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this manual simply hasn't been updated for PHP 7.

PHP 7 **[has changed how errors are reported](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)**:

> PHP 7 changes how most errors are reported by PHP. Instead of reporting errors through the traditional error reporting mechanism used by PHP 5, most errors are now reported by throwing [Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) exceptions.
>
> ...
>
> As the [Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) hierarchy does not inherit from [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), code that uses `catch (Exception $e) { ... }` blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in PHP 5 will find that these [Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php)s are not caught by these blocks. Either a `catch (Error $e) { ... }` block or a [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) handler is required.

In PHP 5.6.38, the above error will be suppressed, with only `hello` being logged. This can be seen **[here](https://3v4l.org/AKDPF)**. This is true even is you turn on all error reporting with `error_reporting(-1)`, as can be seen **[here](https://3v4l.org/Y4eOJ)**. Again, this is contrary to the PHP manual:

> Passing in the value *-1* will show every possible error, even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions

Ironically, if you turn off error reporting with `error_reporting(0)`, then the error message will be suppressed in PHP 7 as well. This can be seen **[here](https://3v4l.org/DMQNk)**.

Comment: This certainly has helped my understanding.  But I'm struggling to find much information on the error control operator prefix (@), some comments and code suggest that it just flips the value of error_reporting to 0 temporarily.  But I can't actually find an official reference for that.

Comment: So in short: errors are raised as exceptions of type Error in Php 7.  And exceptions can't be suppressed with the use of the error control operator prefix: @.